# Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, incompatibletypeerror

In Objective C, I have:

```
NSMutableArray *retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableString *justTest = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"hello"];
unsigned char ch = //anything
[retVal insertObject:[justTest appendFormat:@"%hhu", ch] atIndex:0]; //error here
```

X Code 5.1.1 gives me an error in the 4th line(as mentioned as comment) as `Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'`

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appendFormat` doesn't return anything, it adjusts the mutable string. You need to do this:

```
NSMutableArray *retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableString *justTest = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"hello"];
unsigned char ch = //anything
[justTest appendFormat:@"%hhu", ch]
[retVal insertObject:justTest atIndex:0]; //error here
```

Comment: Ok got it!! Thats why compiler was crying about the `void`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a read of the [Apple Documentation for `NSMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-appendFormat_) you will find that the instance method `appendString:` doesn't actually return a value. It adds a structured string to the end of the receive and that's it.

So when you do `[retVal insertObject:[justTest appendFormat:@"%hhu", ch] atIndex:0];` you are actually really doing `[retVal insertObject:void atIndex:0];` and obviously you can't pass `void` in as a parameter which expects a valid object of `id`.

Here's the method declaration: `- (void)appendFormat:(NSString *)format ...` which you can see has a return type of `void`.

So what you need to be doing is you need to make the amendment to the string before you pass it into the `insertObject:atIndex:` method.

So change to

```
[justTest appendFormat:@"%hhu", ch]; // Append to existing string, DOESN'T return anything
[retVal insertObject:justTest atIndex:0]; // Pass string in as object at index
```

Answer (score 0):

`[justTest appendFormat:@"%hhu", ch]` return void.
You need:

```
[retVal insertObject:([justTest appendFormat:@"%hhu", ch],justTest) atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Yes that was the case. I had to accept @James 's answer as he got it first.

Comment: @Sibir, ok, but my solution is one line shorter.